# Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet::listWorksheetNames

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I want to list all sheets name from workbook, but i get the following error:

`Call to undefined method PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet::listWorksheetNames()`

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
 
$inputFileName = 'uploads/1.xlsx';
$spreadsheet = IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$worksheetNames = $spreadsheet->listWorksheetNames();

echo '<h3>Worksheet Names</h3>';
echo '<ol>';
foreach ($worksheetNames as $worksheetName) {
    echo '<li>', $worksheetName, '</li>';
}
echo '</ol>';
?>
```

I tried to repeat by: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-files/#reading-only-named-worksheets-from-a-file

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing line 8 to `$spreadsheet = IOFactory::createReader($inputFileName);`.

If you take a look at the file [IOFactory#L61](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/fcd9f10663c5be8e435fd0f92c077a8d8747ded1/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php#L61) you'll be able to notice that `createReader` returns a **Reader\IReader** object.

On other hand, function `load` at [the same file](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/fcd9f10663c5be8e435fd0f92c077a8d8747ded1/src/PhpSpreadsheet/IOFactory.php#L80) returns a **Spreadsheet** object.

Function `listWorksheetNames` belongs to Readers, as you can see, for example, at [Reader/Xlsx.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/fcd9f10663c5be8e435fd0f92c077a8d8747ded1/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Reader/Xlsx.php#L100).

Putting it simply: you can only call `listWorksheetNames` on a Reader object.